# delete row in an html doc using python

Tags: python, html

I am writing a python script that writes html code into an html document. However, printing into the html doc is the only thing I can do. I often have extra rows that I don't need, so I'm not sure how to delete the rows by only printing? I've tried using the

```
deleteRow(index)
```

method, but it doesn't work because I have not created any table objects. I can only write html code inside, such as

```
Resultfile.write("<td> %s </td>" %line)
Resultfile.write("<td> 0 </td>")
```

Please, if you don't like my question, don't mark it down. I'm new to stackoverflow, and with only one reputation I can't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are working in the context of append-only operations from the file point of view, you should add everything you want to write into a `list` first, scan it and delete what you do not want, and then write to a file.

More specifically, you can create `myLines = []`, and replace all occurrences of `Resultfile.write` with `myLines.append`.

Then, you would loop through a copy of `myLines` and only keep those lines which you like.

Finally, you loop through the remaining items and call `Resultfile.write` on each item.

```
for item in myLines:
   Resultfile.write(item)
```

Comment: Ok thanks, it worked. I would have upped your answer, but I don't have the needed reputation. Please vote up my question so that I can have more privileges!